# Dynamic add and delete elements with c:forEach tags

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I write some code - I need add and remove dynamic rows with inputTextarea. It works, but after delete and add some value - the value inside inputTextarea change incorrectly. I use

```
    <jsf.version>2.2.8</jsf.version>
    <primefaces.version>3.0</primefaces.version>
```

My bean

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class HelloWorld {
    private final static List<String> ENTITIES = Arrays.asList(new String[]{"1", "2", "3", "4", "5"});

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        selectedFields = ENTITIES.stream().filter(s -> !"5".equals(s)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        availableFields = ENTITIES.stream().filter(s -> "5".equals(s)).collect(Collectors.toList());
        values.put("1", "1");
        values.put("2", "2");
        values.put("3", "");
        values.put("4", "");
    }

    private String selectedType = "";
    private List<String> availableFields;
    private List<String> selectedFields;
    private Map<String, String> values = new HashMap<String, String>();

    public List<String> getAvailableFields() {
        return availableFields;
    }

    public void setAvailableFields(List<String> availableFields) {
        this.availableFields = availableFields;
    }

    public List<String> getSelectedFields() {
        return selectedFields;
    }

    public void setSelectedFields(List<String> selectedFields) {
        this.selectedFields = selectedFields;
    }

    public Map<String, String> getValues() {
        return values;
    }

    public void setValues(Map<String, String> values) {
        this.values = values;
    }

    public void changeOfferType(String type) {
        Optional<String> f = availableFields.stream().filter(s -> s.equals(type)).findFirst();
        selectedFields.add(f.get());
        availableFields.remove(f.get());
        values.put(f.get(), null);
    }

    public void onDelete(String type) {
        Optional<String> f = selectedFields.stream().filter(s -> s.equals(type)).findFirst();
        selectedFields.remove(f.get());
        availableFields.add(f.get());
        values.put(f.get(), null);
    }

    public String getSelectedType() {
        return selectedType;
    }

    public void setSelectedType(String selectedType) {
        this.selectedType = selectedType;
    }
}
```

My xhtml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets">

<h:head>
    <title>PrimeFaces Hello World Example</title>
</h:head>

<h:body>
    <h:form>
        <p:panel id="main">
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">
                <h:outputText value="Add value"
                              style="vertical-align: top; width: 200px;"/>
                <p:selectOneMenu
                        widgetVar="offerType" id="offerType"
                        style="width: 350px"
                        value="#{helloWorld.selectedType}">
                    <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel=""/>
                    <f:selectItems value="#{helloWorld.availableFields}" var="def" itemLabel="#{def}" itemValue="#{def}"/>
                    <p:ajax event="change"
                            update="main"
                            listener="#{helloWorld.changeOfferType(helloWorld.selectedType)}"/>/>
                </p:selectOneMenu>
            </h:panelGrid>
            <h:panelGroup id="panelRepeatWrapper">
                <c:forEach id="panelRepeat" items="#{helloWorld.selectedFields}" var="field">
                    <h:panelGrid columns="3">
                        <h:outputText value="#{field}"
                                      style="vertical-align: top; width: 200px;"/>
                        <h:inputTextarea value="#{helloWorld.values[field]}"
                                         style="width: 550px; height: 50px;"/>
                        <p:commandLink value="x" action="#{helloWorld.onDelete(field)}" update="main">
                        </p:commandLink>
                    </h:panelGrid>
                </c:forEach>
            </h:panelGroup>
        </p:panel>
    </h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

Later, I add github repo with example, which may run on jetty

This images below show - what happened after delete and add the second element - the value of third element is not 3, but 2
What's wrong at the code?!

[wrong](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zqsa8.png)

UPDATE 05.08.2019
I improve my code by using [Dynamic add and delete elements with c:forEach tags](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57203192/dynamic-add-and-delete-elements-with-cforeach-tags#comment100917853_57203192)
The error with add or delete row doesn't repeat, but the new one create.
When I add or edit some value in inputTextarea and then add new row - value in the inputTextarea is incorrect (not adding or not editing)

Why add value not affecting on backing bean attribute values?

New error https://i.stack.imgur.com/9YMxM.png

Comment: You can edit your questin and add the image there

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JSTL in JSF2 Facelets... makes sense?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342984/jstl-in-jsf2-facelets-makes-sense)

Comment: The remote command approach is strange. You're basically creating a new remote command in every loop instead of using only one outside the loop. Moreover, why not just using something like `action="#{helloWorld.onDelete(field)}` in the command button instead of the whole remote command approach?

Comment: @BalusC I used remote command - because it was almost working decision for me after some failing tries. But I try to use simple action inside commandButton and preliminarily thats working. Tomorrow, I fully checked it in real, more difficult case.